# MySQL - Fix my poor performing UPDATE?

Tags: mysql

I have an event which fires periodically to 'abort' some abandoned games (a simple matching server).

This update is proving very (VERY) slow and I'm looking for advice on doing this better.

Problematic Update:

```
  UPDATE user SET skill=skill+
    (SELECT count(participant_1) * 25 FROM matches    
      WHERE score_2 IS NULL 
      AND score_2_time IS NOT NULL 
      AND participant_1=user.id 
      AND score_2_time < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR) 
      AND status=0);
```

Matches table:

```
matches CREATE TABLE `matches` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `match_hash` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `skill` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `participant_1` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `score_1` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `score_1_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `participant_1_rematched` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `participant_2` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `score_2` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `score_2_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `participant_2_rematched` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `finished_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=40667 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

User table:

```
user    CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `skill` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1876 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try not using a nested `SELECT`, something like `UPDATE user u SET u.skill = COUNT(*) * 25 FROM matches m WHERE m.score_2 IS NULL AND m.score_2_time IS NOT NULL AND m.participant_1 = u.id AND m.score_2_time < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND m.status = 0 GROUP BY m.participant_1;`.

Comment: Or is it `UPDATE u SET u.skill = COUNT(*) * 25 FROM user u INNER JOIN matches m ON m.score_2 IS NULL AND m.score_2_time IS NOT NULL AND m.participant_1 = u.id AND m.score_2_time < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND m.status = 0` ? I can't test syntax now.

Comment: Mind this is updating the entire `user` table so it figures it's expensive to run, but using a nested `SELECT` makes matters worse.

Comment: Thanks @Havenard, yep, the nested select is nasty - but seems adding an index on participant_1 is sufficient for now. I'll look into trying your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need more indexes on the `matches` table, certainly at least `participant_1`, and whatever else is mentioned in the WHERE clause that helps. Probably `participant_1` should be a foreign key into `user.id` for integrity reasons.

Comment: "You need more indexes" --- do you mean OP needs to create more single-column indexes?

Comment: @zerkms I meant what I said.

Comment: The problem with how you said it is: beginners would treat it exactly, and given that mysql may only use one* index per table - this advice would be treated in a wrong and misleading way. In general an advice "add more indexes" is plain wrong. Not to speak some of those fields are of low cardinality, so adding a single-column (b-tree) index makes no sense for them.

Comment: @zerkms The advice to add an index on `participant_1` is certainly *not* plain wrong. He *certainly* needs that index, and I strongly suspect that that alone is sufficient. All he has at the moment is `id`, which is unused in the inner query. I can't be responsible for how you or anybody else may misread what I write, but I do take some considerable trouble to express myself clearly.

Comment: "certainly at least participant_1, and whatever else is mentioned in the WHERE clause that helps" --- this is misleading and if is treated exactly - wrong, sorry. Downvoted because as-is it's dangerous for the beginners.

Comment: @zerkms If you're going to quibble get it right. If it doesn't help, as you allege, don't do it, which is what I said.

Comment: So @zerkms' unsourced and anachronistic claim that 'MySQL may only use one index per table' is clearly false. Or else his advice is 'dangerous for beginners'.

Comment: An asterisk there is for purpose. In this very case - there is no possibility mysql would use any other single index than `participant_1`. I can explain it, but who needs my explanation given you're passive agressive from the very beginning. You don't want to improve your answer so that it addressed beginners - I understand it, not sure why bother spending more time here.

Answer (score -1):

Try this query:

```
update user a join (SELECT participant_1,count(participant_1) * 25 as count FROM matches    
      WHERE score_2 IS NULL 
      AND score_2_time IS NOT NULL 
      AND score_2_time < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR) 
      AND status=0 group by participant_1) b on a.id=b.participant_1 SET a.skill=a.skill+b.count
```

Comment: Please add an explanation.